# If I wanted to reinstall my Windows 7 Pro OEM, what would happen on activation?

Tags: windows-7

My sister's old work laptop is finally showing signs of aging, and she wants to reformat it to start over.

It's running a Windows 7 Pro (OEM) that she bought herself, as the laptop previously only came with a trial version of Home.

So, my question is, what would happen on activation? Would Windows 7 have installed the key onto her motherboard and she doesn't need to re-enter the key?

Or if she does need to re-enter the key, what would happen? Would it just work? Do we need some activation procedure?

We can't really do the phone activation as
a.) We don't have a phone
b.) We're in the Philippines

Comment: It would activate.  If it does not then phone activation will be required.  The Windows 7 license key WILL NOT be automatically detected, that's only a feature on Windows 8+ devices, the Windows 7 license key is on the COA sticker that came with the Windows 7 Professional OEM disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She needs to reenter the key but should work otherwise. "Small system builder" OEM installers are more similar to retail than the SLP enabled installs large builders use in that respect.

It *should* activate fine. You can do a few things to ease the process though  You'll need an install key - [nirsoft produkey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) should let you find out what it was .

*Since* its windows 7,  [Advanced Tokens Manager](http://joshcellsoftwares.com/products/advancedtokensmanager/) would let you backup and restore the activation tokens, which would be handy if online activation fails.

Nonetheless, there's a good chance this would be fairly painless

Comment: She still has the key and the disc, or is the install key something different?

Comment: The one on the jewel case should be the same as the one you retrieve. I typically lose these things and keep ISOs so I prefer to retrieve the key on the system, *and* the tokens in this situation.